# No results from Azure Cognitive Services Image Search API when imageType query parameter is set to "Shopping"

Tags: azure-cognitive-services

I am trying to use the Microsoft Cognitive Services Image Search API to search for images and return ecommerce results.

Until recently, this was working perfectly, but now any searches I perform with the query parameter `imageType: 'Shopping'` come back empty. If I perform the same search with any other imageType filter, or without the filter at all, I get many results, including many results where insightsSourcesSummary.shoppingSourcesCount is greater than 0.

Here is the code I wrote to call the API:

```
const
  promise = require('bluebird');
  rp = require('request-promise');

var Bing = function () {};

Bing.prototype.imageSearch = function(q, count) {
  var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    uri: "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search",
    qs: {
      q: q,
      count: count,
      mkt: 'en-us',
      safeSearch: 'Moderate',
      imageType: 'Shopping'
    },
    headers: {
        'Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key': '****************'
    },
    json: true
  };

  return rp(options);
}

module.exports = Bing;
```

Again, I did not change any code between October 2016 when it was working, and now when it is not. Is this a new bug with the API or something I'm doing wrong?

Edited: a curl example for your convenience (you will need to specify a subscription key):

```
curl -H "Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key:****************" "https://api.cognitive.microsoft.com/bing/v5.0/images/search?q=shoes&imageType=Shopping"
```

Comment: Can you share some more details?  That search works fine for me, and I checked the history of those searches for the last 2 days and they all worked correctly.  When you say the response comes back empty, do you mean you get 0 results, or the actual response body is completely empty?  Do you have a timestamp and/or request ID?

Comment: @kwill Absolutely. I mean that the `value` field comes back as an empty array, and the `totalEstimatedMatches` field does not come back at all. If I remove the imageType filter, the `value` field comes back with result objects, and the `totalEstimatedMatches` field is `1000`

Comment: @kwill Just ran the query again, here are the headers with some removed because of the SO character count limitations:
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Vary: Accept-Encoding
P3P: CP="NON UNI COM NAV STA LOC CURa DEVa PSAa PSDa OUR IND"
BingAPIs-TraceId: 11D16D9511334BD38C82BCEECC673F46
X-MSEdge-ClientID: 2DEFA5B4680F696A13CCAFC6699F6844
X-MSAPI-UserState: 494d
X-MSEdge-Ref: Ref A
apim-request-id: 3da92560-dbfc-4990-ae45-fc6ec535afdb
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Date: Fri, 28 Apr 2017 18:49:28 GMT